# Markov Chain Monte Carlo, proposal distribution for multivariate Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability, montecarlo, markov-chains

Is there a suitable proposal distribution for multivariate Bernoulli model ?

for example I want to sample from a probability distribution

```
    p(x) = p*(x) / Z;
```

where x = {0,1}^M and Z is the normalization constant, Which is intractable to directly draw independent samples, so I resort to MCMC.

For multivariate continuous data, it is trivial to use Gaussian as a proposal distribution.
Is there a suitable proposal distribution on such binary type data ?

p.s. I don't want to use Gibbs sampling because it is too slow for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found exactly what I want, which appears in last year's NIPS conference:

"Auxiliary-variable Exact Hamiltonian Monte Carlo Samplers for Binary Distributions"

Ari Pakman et al.

http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~liam/research/pubs/pakman-exact-binary-hmc.pdf

Comment: You really need to explain your model, otherwise this is of no use to anyone as a question/answer pair. Why is it not possible to sample from each of the marginals independently to get a draw from p(x)? In the MVB model the marginals are independent

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have to explain your model better. For standard variants of the multivariate Bernoulli model, Z is the dimensionality of x since the sum of probabilities over possible outcomes for each marginal is 1, and there's no dependence between the x_is.